# How to setup GSuite domain with Firebase SMTP

Tags: firebase, google-workspace

What is the CORRCT way to add my google suite account details to the smtp form? And is this a safety concern? If I set up my SMTP settings, will it now send the verification email link from that account?

Also, if I have a gsuite domain, should I still do this or should I be adding the domain by verifying through firebase?

I just want my verification emails to look like they are coming from a professional company rather than a sandbox no-reply account.

Comment: Hi Denis, did you ever figure out the answer? I am trying to set this up with the SMTP setting from this page: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en. But no success so far.

Comment: It worked after enabling LSA. However, LSA access will be discontinued between mid 2020 and beginning 2021. So this will probably stop working soon. More info about discontinuation of LSA can be found here: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps explained below, I have shared a medium post about it if you would like to have more details.

1. Enable the 2 step verification for the G Suite account.
2. Create an app password for the account.
3. Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps
4. Unlock the captcha

The G-Suite account is ready to be used as an SMTP service for firebase.

Check [this link](https://medium.com/patron-ai/g-suite-mail-as-smtp-service-for-firebase-auth-ec0483d21bb1) please for more details.

Comment: On point 3 I see the message "This setting is managed by your domain administrator." on the page titled "Less secure app access", but I have been given complete admin permissions on the account.